# how to write status output depending on time?

Tags: python, django

How to write status output depending on time?

I have a task in which I had a small problem, namely in the use of time, if less than a day has passed, then assign the status "Waiting" ('e'), if more than a day has passed, then the status "Ready" ('rd' ).
Here is a part of my code, here it is just creating a ticket and immediately assigning "Waiting". 
Please help me with how I set the status of Waiting ('e'), if less than a day has passed, the status Ready ('rd'), if more than a day has passed. Thank you in advance for your help or for hints!

```
class PatientAcceptVisitView(AbsPatientVie
    template_name = 'patient/accept_visit.html'

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk_visit = context.get('pk_visit')
        visit = CoreVisit.get(pk=pk_visit)
        visit.guid_user_patient = self.request.user.guid_user
        visit.type = visit.VISIT_TYPES[2]
        visit.date_appointment = timezone.now()
        visit.save()
        PatientConsultationTicket.objects.create(pk_visit=pk_visit, 
        creator=self.request.user,
        consultation_time=visit.date_visit_start, status='e')
        visit_start_as_text = visit.date_visit_start.strftime("%H:%M день %d.%m.%Y")
        messages.info(request, f'Вы записались на {visit_start_as_text} к доктору {context.get("doctor")}')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('patient:visits'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a view that shows the status of the PatientConsultationTicket, you can check the date and then update the status while you are giving the response.

So say you have a have a method which shows the ticket to the user

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class TicketDetailView(View):

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        ticket = PatientConsultationTicket.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        one_day_mark = ticket.created_at + timedelta(days=1)
        if datetime.now() > one_day_mark:
            ticket.status = 'rd'
            ticket.save()
        # context and other logic
        return render(request, 'patient/ticket_detail.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use time delta for such task (Python +3.6):

```
import datetime

one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

now = datetime.datetime.now()

if now - date_visit_start > one_day:
    # ...
else:
   # ...
```